# Slicing an array in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I have an array 'b' as follows,

```
int[] b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

and I want to slice this array to get an output array 'a', as

```
int[] a = [1,2,3];
```

Currently, I'm using the following steps.

```
function main(string... args) {

    int[] b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

    int[] a;
    int val = 0;

    foreach e in  b{

        a[val] = e;
        io:println(a);
        val++;

        if (val>2) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, or is there a separate method in Ballerina?

Comment: There is a builtin slice command for this in never versions. You should be able to do int[] a = b.slice(0, 3). There is a length problem in sliced arrays which will get changed. https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/api-docs/ballerina/lang.array/functions.html#slice

Comment: Issue tracking the sliced array length. https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/20574

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Ballerina integer ranges [1] array can be sliced like following.

```
int[] b = [10, 22, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]; 
int[] a;
foreach i in 0 ... 2 {
    a[i]  = b[i];
}
```

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/integer-ranges.html

Comment: This answer is not correct. Try the following code snippet and see the answer. 
int[] b = [10, 22, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80];
int[] a = b [0] ... b [2];